# Undelete a deleted google workspace user via google admin sdk/api using postman

Tags: google-api, postman, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

Did anyone used undelete command to restore the deleted users using google admin SDK API in google workspace ?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/undelete

I want to undelete a user who is recently delete but the command requires a {userKey}, is string (The immutable id of the user), which i don't know where and how to find out:

HTTP request

POST [https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}/undelete](https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/%7BuserKey%7D/undelete)

Can anyone help me with below :

1. We need to send a request to find this user's immutable id.
2. Using that ID we will be able to undelete it
3. add the user to org A.D
4. any other thing which would be required after that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have tried deleting a user, where it only requires "Email address" as identifier.
I have tried to get users details, where it only requires "Email address" as identifier.

But when i try to undelete, using "email address" as userkey it doesn't recognise that user as it is already deleted.

Answer (score 1):

### **Suggestion: Use the `users.list` method**

Unlike the delete method, you cannot use the user's email address in the `userKey` field when restoring them. You would have to use the 21-character userID instead. On the [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) method, specify your domain name on the `domain` field and enter **true** on the `showDeleted` field to filter the deleted users.

### Sample screenshot of the parameters on the users.list API explorer:

[image: users.list params]

### Expected result:

[image: result]

---

In addition, I recommend specifying the `orgUnitPath` when running the `users.undelete` method.

### user.Undelete sample request params:

[image]

### Reference:

- [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list)

Comment: Feel free to leave a comment in case you have additional questions regarding the answer I posted.

Comment: great....making showDeleted as true started showing the user in result, and then using their id i was able to undelete the user.  Thanks Alot