# Undelete a deleted Google workspace user

Tags: google-api

Did anyone used undelete command to restore the deleted users using google admin SDK API in google workspace ?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/undelete

I want to undelete a `user` who is recently delete but the command requires a {userKey}, is string (The immutable id of the user), which i don't know where and how to find out:

HTTP request

POST [https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/{userKey}/undelete](https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/%7BuserKey%7D/undelete)

Can anyone help me with below :

We need to send a request to find this user's immutable id.
Using that ID we will be able to undelete it
add the user to org A.D
any other thing which would be required after that.
Thanks in advance for any help.

What I have tried:

I have tried deleting a user, where it only requires "Email address" as identifier. I have tried to get users details, where it only requires "Email address" as identifier.

But when i try to undelete, using "email address" as userkey it doesn't recognise that user as it is already deleted.

Comment: Is this not the same post as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77106144/undelete-a-deleted-google-workspace-user-via-google-admin-sdk-api-using-postman ? The other post already has an answer.